# Teamcity build agent suffering due to corrupt config file

Tags: git, teamcity

How would I go about resolving this? I've tried cleaning sources and restarting the build agent, but still getting the same message. We have a second build agent that is working fine. My biggest issue is that I have no physical access to the build agents.

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: Problem while checkout on agent: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository config file C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-F58F7104.git\config invalid Cannot read file C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-F58F7104.git\config
```

Comment: How about constructing a separate job with a command line step that digs in the respective folder, locking it to only run on the faulty agent, and then execute it? If needs be you can also clean out directories using the command line. Also, *somebody* has access to the build agents, so perhaps you should talk to your administrator?

Comment: And by "no physical access", do you mean not even remote desktop?

Comment: Yeah, no remote desktop, not in the next 48 hours anyway, admin is out of town. It's complicated, but also not critical. I'll have a go as you suggested, nice idea.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that got things rolling again. I created a single-step build that just renamed the corrupt file, and now we are functional.